# 's3.ServiceResource' does not have the 'get_object' attribute when I try to get the data inside the json files in an S3 bucket

Tags: python, python-3.x, amazon-s3, aws-lambda

I am a beginner with AWS lambda and AWS in general. I'm trying to make a 20 ".json" extract from an S3 bucket. So I did the following in an AmazonS3 lambda function:

```
import json
import boto3

s3 = boto3.resource('s3')

def lambda_handler(event, context):
    bucket_name = 'jom-data'
    prefix = "reviews/ch/tmall"
    keys = []
    # list of 100 keys
    d = {}
    i = 0
    bucket = s3.Bucket(bucket_name)
    for object_summary in bucket.objects.filter(Prefix=prefix):
        key = object_summary.key
        print("key: ", key)
        if key.endswith(".json"):
            response = s3.get_object(Bucket=bucket, Key=key)
            print("response: ", response)
            content = response['Body']
            print("content: ", content)
            jsonObject = json.loads(content.read())
            
            d[i]["name"] = jsonObject["name"]
            d[i]["chinese_name"] = jsonObject["chinese_name"]
            d[i]["reviews"] = jsonObject["reviews"]
            print(jsonObject["name"])
            i += 1
            if i>=20:
                return d
```

But it returns:

```
Test Event Name
TestEvent

Response
{
  "errorMessage": "'s3.ServiceResource' object has no attribute 'get_object'",
  "errorType": "AttributeError",
  "requestId": "699121cb-8038-42a8-9fc2-2596fc87bf94",
  "stackTrace": [
    "  File \"/var/task/lambda_function.py\", line 18, in lambda_handler\n    response = s3.get_object(Bucket=bucket, Key=key)\n"
  ]
}

Function Logs
START RequestId: 699121cb-8038-42a8-9fc2-2596fc87bf94 Version: $LATEST
key:  reviews/ch/tmall/
key:  reviews/ch/tmall/018883e290636d782895.json
[ERROR] AttributeError: 's3.ServiceResource' object has no attribute 'get_object'
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/var/task/lambda_function.py", line 18, in lambda_handler
    response = s3.get_object(Bucket=bucket, Key=key)END RequestId: 699121cb-8038-42a8-9fc2-2596fc87bf94
REPORT RequestId: 699121cb-8038-42a8-9fc2-2596fc87bf94  Duration: 486.99 ms Billed Duration: 487 ms Memory Size: 128 MB Max Memory Used: 70 MB  Init Duration: 346.63 ms

Request ID
699121cb-8038-42a8-9fc2-2596fc87bf94
```

I just tried Dan-Dev answer but got:

```
Test Event Name
TestEvent

Response
{
  "errorMessage": "2022-03-03T23:15:45.099Z b9251135-0b93-4951-96be-44a9ea057fcc Task timed out after 3.00 seconds"
}

Function Logs
\u5915\u7684\u793c\u7269\uff0c\u9999\u5473\u8fd8\u6ca1\u8bd5\uff0c\u4e0d\u8fc7\u989c\u503c\u5f88\u80fd\u6253", "\u74f6\u8eab\u8bbe\u8ba1\uff1a\u5f88\u7cbe\u81f4", "\u74f6\u8eab\u597d\u770b\uff0c\u5473\u9053\u597d\u95fb\uff0c\u7559\u9999\u6301\u4e45\uff0c\u975e\u5e38\u6ee1\u610f", "\u793c\u76d2\u90fd\u4e0d\u9001\u7684\u4e48\uff1f", "\u597d\u95fb\uff0c\u6301\u60f3\u6548\u679c\u4e0d\u957f\uff0c\u5c0f\u5c0f\u65f6", "\u5df4\u58eb", "\u771f\u7684\u8d85\u9999\u7684\uff0c\u4e5f\u4e0d\u662f\u5f88\u6d53\u7684\u90a3\u79cd\uff0c\u9999\u5473\u521a\u521a\u597d\uff0c\u662f\u6211\u559c\u6b22\u7684\u9999\u5473\uff0c\u9001\u7684\u5c0f\u6837\u4e5f\u5f88\u597d\u95fb\uff0c\u8fd8\u4f1a\u56de\u8d2d\u7684\u3002", "\u7b2c\u4e00\u6b21\u4e70\u9999\u6c34\u9001\u5973\u5b69\u5b50\uff0c\u5bf9\u65b9\u5f88\u6ee1\u610f", "\u670b\u53cb\u5f88\u559c\u6b22\uff0c\u597d\u8bc4\uff01", "\u6574\u4f53\u8bc4\u4ef7\uff1a\u5e97\u5bb6\u9999\u6c3435\u6beb\u5347\u7684\u5356790\uff0c\u552f\u54c1\u4f1a50\u6beb\u5347\u7684\u5356850\uff0c\u6211\u8001\u5a46\u8ba9\u6211\u4e70\u4e00\u74f6\uff0c\u6211\u4e5f\u6ca1\u5408\u8ba1\u5c31\u5728\u6dd8\u5b9d\u4e70\u4e86\uff0c\u6700\u53ef\u6c14\u7684\u90fd\u662f\u6b63\u54c1\uff0c\u5473\u9053\u90fd\u662f\u4e00\u6837\u7684\uff0c\u4f46\u662f\u5dee\u7684\u94b1\u592a\u591a\u4e86\uff0c\u6211\u611f\u89c9\u771f\u4e0d\u503c\u554a\uff01", "\u5473\u9053\u8fd8\u884c\uff0c\u5c31\u662f\u65f6\u95f4\u4e0d\u957f\u3002\u65e9\u4e0a\u7528\u4e86\u4e2d\u5348\u5c31\u6ca1\u5565\u5473\u4e86", "\u5f88\u597d.\u6ca1\u6311\u9519.\u5927\u4eba\u6ee1\u610f", "\u5e2e\u5144\u5f1f\u4e70\u7684 \u4ed6\u9001\u4eba \u8bf4\u5f88\u597d\u7528", "\u5fc3\u5100\u5f88\u9577\u6642\u9593\u53fb\u9999", "\u611f\u8c22\u9999\u5948\u513f", "\u6574\u4f53\u8bc4\u4ef7\uff1a\u56de\u8d2d\u7684\u5927\u74f6\u548c\u5c0f\u74f6\uff0c\u5c0f\u74f6\u65b9\u4fbf\u5e26\u51fa\u95e8\uff0c\u6700\u7231\u7684\u662f\u7c89\u8272\u8fd9\u6b3e\uff0c\u6c14\u5473\uff0c\u4e00\u95fb\u5c31\u7acb\u9a6c\u56de\u8d2d\u7684\u6c14\u5473", "\u5473\u9053\u4e0d\u9519\u7684\uff0c\u5c31\u662f\u53ea\u80fd\u6301\u7eed\u534a\u5929\ud83d\ude02\ud83d\ude02", "\u8d28\u91cf\u6ca1\u5f97\u8bf4\uff0c\u8ddf\u4e13\u5356\u5e97\u4e00\u6837\uff0c\u7279\u522b\u7279\u522b\u559c\u6b22\uff0c\u800c\u4e14\u4ef7\u683c\u4f18\u60e0", "\u8fd8\u6ca1\u7528\uff0ctinghaode", "\u633a\u597d\u5f97", "\u987a\u4e30\u5bc4\u8fc7\u6765\u7684\uff0c\u5c0f\u54e5\u670d\u52a1\u597d", "\u9999\u5948\u513f\u9999\u6c34\u597d\uff0c\u6211\u4e00\u76f4\u559c\u6b22\u8fd9\u6b3e\u9999\u6c34\u3002\u5305\u88c5\u597d\u5927\u724c\u5c31\u662f\u597d\u3002\u5feb\u9012\u5feb\uff01\u8fd8\u9001\u5c0f\u6837\u3002\u6211\u597d\u559c\u6b22\ud83d\udc4c\ud83d\udc4d\ud83d\udc4d\ud83d\udc6d", "\u8fd9\u624d\u4e70\u51e0\u5929\u5c31\u964d\u4ef7\u90a3\u4e48\u591a\u4e86\uff1f\uff01\u4e70\u65f6850\u73b0\u5728640\uff01\u8ba9\u4eba\u6709\u79cd\u4e0a\u5f53\u53d7\u9a97\u7684\u611f\u89c9", "\u6de1\u9999\u6301\u4e45", "\u7b2c\u4e8c\u74f6\uff01\u4e13\u67dc\u4e70\u7684\u7c89\u8272\u5473\u9053\u4e0d\u7231\u2026", "\u521a\u55b7\u7684\u65f6\u5019\u5473\u9053\u6709\u70b9\u5927\uff0c\u540e\u52b2\u597d\u95fb\uff0c\u559c\u6b22\u7684\u4e70\u5b83\ud83d\ude0b", "\u633a\u9999\u7684\uff0c\u4e5f\u6301\u4e45\uff0c\u633a\u6ee1\u610f\u3002", "\u719f\u6089\u7684\u5473\u9053\uff0c\u4e70\u9999\u6c34\u8fd8\ud83c\ude50\ufe0f\u4e0a\u5b98\u65b9\u6b63\u54c1\u5e97\u2026\u2026\u4ee5\u540e\u4f1a\u5e38\u6765\u7684", "\u975e\u5e38\u706b\u5927\uff0c\u53d1\u8d27\u6162\u7684\u4e00\u584c\u7cca\u6d82\u4e14\u4e0d\u8bf4\u3002\u6211\u4e70\u4e86\u4e24\u74f6\uff0c\u7ed9\u6211\u5305\u88c5\u5728\u4e00\u4e2a\u76d2\u5b50\u91cc\uff0c\u6ca1\u6709\u793c\u54c1\u888b\u3002\u600e\u4e48\u9001\u4e24\u4e2a\u4eba\u3002"]}
CHANCE EAU TENDRE
[INFO]  2022-03-03T23:15:45.61Z b9251135-0b93-4951-96be-44a9ea057fcc    key: reviews/ch/tmall/c977e1aa357b27adbd05.json
END RequestId: b9251135-0b93-4951-96be-44a9ea057fcc
REPORT RequestId: b9251135-0b93-4951-96be-44a9ea057fcc  Duration: 3000.90 ms    Billed Duration: 3000 ms    Memory Size: 128 MB Max Memory Used: 75 MB  Init Duration: 336.93 ms    
2022-03-03T23:15:45.099Z b9251135-0b93-4951-96be-44a9ea057fcc Task timed out after 3.00 seconds

Request ID
b9251135-0b93-4951-96be-44a9ea057fcc
```

Answer (score 1):

If you are using `boto3.resource` and don't (or can't) want to change it to `boto3.client` then you can do `resource.meta.client.get_object` or other apis from the boto3 client.

In your case:

```py
import boto3

s3 = boto3.resource('s3')

s3.meta.client.get_object(...)
```

Answer (score 0):

You were using a `boto3.resource` https://boto3.amazonaws.com/v1/documentation/api/latest/reference/services/s3.html#service-resource which has limited functionality and was giving you the error. Instead, you want to be using `boto3.client` https://boto3.amazonaws.com/v1/documentation/api/latest/reference/services/s3.html#client. I would recommend you use logging instead of printing, it will write to your CloudWatch logs.

```
import json
import boto3
import logging

LOGGER = logging.getLogger()
LOGGER.setLevel(logging.INFO)

s3_client = boto3.client('s3')


def lambda_handler(event, context):
    bucket = 'jom-data'
    prefix = "reviews/ch/tmall"
    for object_summary in s3_client.list_objects(Bucket=bucket, Prefix=prefix)['Contents']:
        key = object_summary['Key']
        LOGGER.info(f'key: {key}')
        if key.endswith(".json"):
            content = s3_client.get_object(Bucket=bucket, Key=key)['Body'].read().decode('utf-8')
            LOGGER.info(f'content: {content}')
            json_object = json.loads(content)
            LOGGER.info(json_object["name"])
            # other JSON manipulation here
```

Comment: Many thanks for your answer! However I have an error `Task timed out` and the logs show the Chinese characters as binary, do you know how to deal with this error so I can parse all the json documents and how I can show the Chinese parameters?

Comment: In the AWS Console go to Lambda -> Functions and select your function go to Configuration -> General configuration and click Edit and adjust the Timeout to 15 minutes. That should fix the timeout issue. Do you know the encoding of the JSON files? Where are you seeing the Chinese characters, on the line `LOGGER.info(f'content: {content}')` or if you try `LOGGER.info(json_object["chinese_name"])` can you post a example/dummy JSON file showing this issue please

Answer (score 0):

change how you "create" s3 as follows :

```py
s3 = boto3.client('s3')
```

You have created s3 as a 'resource' - hence the error.